# Keep getting "param is missing errors" while trying to pass an array and a hidden field to create a new object(s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having some problems getting my form to work. Going through the Odin stuff, I'm trying to allow users to invite other users to their event. I'd like to do this by passing the attended_event_id in the background and then pass an array of user_ids of selected users via checkbox. I HAD the following but was constantly getting param missing errors. I made some changes and want to try working backwards FROM my strong params backwards to my form.

events/show.html.erb

```
<% @user.owned_events.each do |e| %>
<ul>
<li><%= e.name %>  |  <%= link_to "Invite Guests", invitations_new_path(:event_select => e.id) %></li>
```

That should pass the current event selected as event_select.

I am then using that event id as well as all of the user ids(minus the current_user) to create a list of possible invitees.

invitations_controller.rb:

```
class InvitationsController < ApplicationController
helper_method :current_user


def new
@event_selected = Event.find(params[:event_select])
@users = User.where("id != ?", current_user.id )
end

def create
@invitation = Invitation.new(invite_params)
end

private

def invite_params
#OLD PARAMS STATEMENT: params.require(:attended_event_id => params[:event_selected], :attendee_id => params[:user_ids].first )

 #NEW PARAMS STATEMENT
     params.require(:invitation).permit(:attended_event_id, :attendee_id)

end

end
```

My view showing the list of users and after selecting a checkbox, should pass the event_selected and user_ids.

invitations/new.html.erb <--- This is where I can't figure out how to change

```
    <h3>Invite users to <%= @event_selected.name %></h3>

<%= bootstrap_form_for Invitation.new do |f| %>
<br>
  <ul>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
    <li>
      <%= hidden_field_tag :event_selected, @event_selected.id %>
  <%= check_box_tag 'user_ids[]', user.id %>
  <%= h user.name %>
  </li>
  <% end %>
  </ul>
<br>
<%= submit_tag "Invite Selected Users" %>
<% end %>
```

I am trying to get this to work to select just a single user at a time before moving to create multiple objects from the selected event combined with all the results in the user_id array. When I select a single user I keep getting the missing param error but looking at the hash, it seems like everything is there.

```
param is missing or the value is empty: {:attended_event_id=>"14", :attendee_id=>"3"}

    Parameters:

 {"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"GMMg9DwnTRAw4qP/ICqgACUB4d42Pl9Y7hrrNQzO38K8inbgyM00H2etrepjrT35hwIenHfwQPQW08V6QnHl1A==",
 "event_selected"=>"14",
 "user_ids"=>["3"],
 "commit"=>"Invite Selected Users"}
```

Pretty new at this coding thing but this is the first problem I haven't been able to solve through a lot stackoverflow searches. I seem to be missing something here.

Comment: Your `params.require...` syntax is wrong. check [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html)

Comment: I have used the standard .require and .permit syntax before but am not connecting what I need to do as I am getting the :attended_event_id param from the @event_selected variable and the attendee_id from the objects being passed back from the user_ids[]. I have gotten to my current solution from various posts on how to try and do this. I am thinking I'm not connecting the examples to my specific problem so any further direction on what I'm doing wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: After having repeated trouble getting this to work, I tried just breaking it down and switching my form to be two text inputs (:attended_event_id and :attendee_id). Now my, question is 1) How do I forward on the :attended_event_id to be picked up after being passed from the event controller. 2) How do I add a list of users with checkboxes, return an array of users, then cycle through the hash and create the invitations? I thought I had it before but couldn't get it to work from the params side so hopefully doing this backwards makes it easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after looking through the links and working backwards, I figured out the first half of this which was giving me the most problems.

```
def invite_params
#OLD PARAMS STATEMENT: 
params.require(:attended_event_id => params[:event_selected], :attendee_id => params[:user_ids].first )

#NEW PARAMS STATEMENT: 
params.require(:invitation).permit(:attended_event_id, :attendee_id)
```

Then I changed my hidden tag to:

```
<%= f.hidden_field :attended_event_id, :value => @event_selected.id %>
```

This allowed me to pass the attended_event_id from the events controller, through the invitations#new to the invitations#create.

Now I just need to figure out how to iterate through the hash as part of params.